Misuse of combining characters (i.e., Zalgo text) overflows all text fields on SO and discussion space
I ran a test on the discussion space and after further testing discovered that combination characters are not confined to their respective text field on the entirety of SO (and probably SE), but rather "spill out" across the site. For exam­ple:
Demonstration of the issue
Reveal the spoiler to show the issue:

 Ever wondered how Stack Overflow handles glitch-text? Of course there are different levels to it some l̸̨ͩͤͫi̸̱͈͉͈̼ͨ͋g̷̡͉̍̈̽︣͟͟͡h̸͚̦͐ț̸̨̾͢, some more s᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷿᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃᷃e͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͕͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝v̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̡̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̓ḛ̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̰̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏̏r͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎ͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫͫë͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎͎̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈.


Obviously this breaks the appearance of this site, as well as the revsion history:

I believe the use of combination characters should not be forbidden per se, as there are valid reasons for using them in posts (Such as asking questions related to well this misuse and other ).
Instead something along the lines of this answer should be implemented, to hide any overflow.

“contain: paint;” may be a very simple modern solution. I haven’t tested it though.

cross-site duplicate: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/363357/237989

I think we should use regex for this.

Frankly, my take on this aligns with rene's. This is intentionally breaking the system in a way that is not a security vulnerability. The problem is the user who does it, not the site. If it's unintentional, you can immediately see the problem and correct it. Even if it doesn't reproduce on your system, someone else can fix it. If a user does this multiple times, raise a moderator flag, and we will make sure it doesn't happen again for at least 1 year.

hm. cannot repro. I'm on chrome 131 on ubuntu 24.04 with x11

I mostly agree with the sentiment that this is more of a rules misbehaviour than something that needs to be technically prevented. However, there are some other formatting bugs that can disrupt the formatting of the rest of the page in a way that can slightly impair the ability of moderators to easily fix it without some degree of technical knowledge to get around the disruption. I haven’t seen anything that’s so bad to the point that it actually can’t be fixed, but I think it’s probably possible with more creativity. “contain: paint” might mitigate those too. Not sure. Testing required.

No repro on Firefox 133, Mint 21.3 / Cinnamon.

I think the "bigger" problem is not the post (as that can be fixed), but the revisions page. The revisions page for this post is a mess now, and could only be fixed by a mod's interaction.

@ThomA still no repro for me - except, curiously, if I check the raw source for revisions.

No repro for me on Ubuntu 22.04 either, @KarlKnechtel . I suspect that due to fonts. On Windows 11 the font is "Segoe UI Adjusted", but on Ubuntu it's "Liberation Sans". Visually, the text looks very different: Windows 11, Ubuntu 22.04

As said it's not the OS but the font that will be in play. So if you want to post "no repro" messages, you should figure out the font that is being used to render the text :)

@Gimby that would surprise to me. I'm not sure if I believe that yet. Why would that be the case? Do fonts have clipping/overflow parameters? I wouldn't have expected this to be a fontface thing. I'd have expected it to be a CSS box / paint containment thing at first, and then maybe default CSS of various browsers set those, and then maybe a difference in how builds of browsers for different platforms do font rendering. I'm too lazy to try with Segoe right now. If I play around with various fonts I have on my current machine other than Liberation Sans, still no repro.

I installed Liberation Sans on my Windows 11 PC and changed the font to it, and I can't repro, so that suggests font to me, @starball . Admittedly, howevery, i know very little able web development, but here's a gif of me changing the HTML and the rendering changing.

@ThomA nice. I wonder if it's not an issue of clipping, but of positioning/stacking.
